# Using different input methods on android accessible application

Tags: java, android, input, accessibility

I'm working on an accessible aplication for blind users, and I want my app to use the input method I configured in app preferences when I focus any EditText.

The input methods are:

- Standard Android keyboard
- Voice recognition
- Gestures

Which is the best way to do this?

I guess one way will be adding a listener on all EditTexts and calling an Activity with the selected input method and obtaining the result with startActivityForResult, but I don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: Don't you think, that blind users has set convenient input method in their system preferences?

Comment: Are these actual input methods that extend InputMethodService, or just activities within your application?